# Displaying CPU usage within a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox, cpu, counter

I have defined an instance as:

```
PerformanceCounter perf =
    new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total", ".");
```

I want this information to be displayed within a RichTextBox. This is how I'm calling the instance:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText("CPU Load: {0}", PerformanceCouner.NextValue());
```

But "NextValue" always has an error attached to it saying:

> CPU_information.PerformanceCounter does not contain a definition for NextValue.

I really need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to call a method on the `PerformanceCounter` class itself, not an instance.

Instead, you need to reference the instance of `PerformanceCounter` you created:

```
perf.NextValue();
```

Your code still won't compile because you forgot `string.Format` too:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("CPU Load: {0}", perf.NextValue()));
```